# If $f(x) = \ln(x)+\arctan(x)$ find $(f^{-1})'(\frac{\pi}{4})$

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = \ln(x)+\arctan(x)$ find $(f^{-1})'(\frac{\pi}{4})$

My answer was $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$

Comment: the response should be a number, not a function

Comment: How do you get a number with a ln?

Comment: I just had this on my test. It made absolutely nosense to me.

Comment: Note that $f(1)=\pi/4$ (and there is no other $x$ such that $f(x)=\pi/4$.) Then by a formula you have seen, the answer to our problem is $\frac{1}{f'(1)}$. You calculated $f'(x)$, so the rest will be easy.

Comment: Just to add to the hint above: $f$ maps $x$ to $y$, and $f^{-1}$ maps $y$ to $x$, so their slopes are related according to the above hint.

Comment: After the edit, you are even closer: plug in $1$ for $x$.  Except you differentiated $\arctan x$ incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difficulty with this kind of problem is that it is very easy to get the variables totally mixed up.  Here is my recommended method.

Let $y=f(x)$ and let $g$ be the inverse of $f$.  That is,
$$x=g(y)\tag{$*$}$$
and the question is asking for $g'(\pi/4)$, that is,
$$\frac{dx}{dy}\quad\hbox{when}\ y=\frac\pi4\ .$$
Differentiate $y=f(x)$ with respect to $y$ to get
$$1=f'(x)\frac{dx}{dy}$$
and so
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac1{f'(x)}=\frac1{\frac1x+\frac1{x^2+1}}\ .\tag{$**$}$$
Problem is, the RHS is in terms of $x$ and we have a value for $y$.  But since $y=f(x)$ we have
$$\frac\pi4=\ln x+\arctan x$$
and by trial and error you can see that $x=1$.  So from $(**)$ you have
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac23\ ,$$
and this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Abbreviating $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ then $f\circ g(x)=x$. Then up on taking derivative $f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$ so
$g'(x)=\dfrac{1}{f'(g(x))}$ translate into
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$

This will help you.